# Cypress before hook repeats after each it statement

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new to cypress when go to a url using a before hook it completes the first it statement, then it executes the before hook again and does the 2nd it statement, it should execute the before hook once execute the it statements and stop. However that is not what is happening and i need help please to see what i am doing wrong. My code is below:

```
import { expect, assert, should } from 'chai';
import LoginPage from '../page-objects/LoginPage.spec'
import BeHomePage from '../page-objects/BeHomePage.spec'

    describe('create, edit, delete Survey', () => {

        before(function() {
            cy.visit(''); // see config json for base url
        })

        it('user can login to boardeffect', () => {          
            LoginPage.getLoginUserName().type(Cypress.env('username'));
            LoginPage.getLoginUserPassword().type(Cypress.env('password'));
            LoginPage.getSigninButton().click();
        })

        it('user can navigate to collaborate', () => {
            BeHomePage.getAutoBeWorkroom().should('be.visible');
            BeHomePage.getAutoBeWorkroom().click();
            BeHomePage.getCollaborate().should('be.visible');
            BeHomePage.getCollaborate().click();
           cy.wait(10000)
        })

    })

{
    "baseUrl": "https://automation-ozzie.boardeffect.com/login",
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 15000,
    
    "env": {
        "username": "steveSystem",
        "password": "Passw0rd"
      }

}
```

class BeHomePage {

```
getAutoBeWorkroom() {
    return cy.get(':nth-child(7) > a')
}

getCollaborate(){
    return cy.get('.workroom-buttons > :nth-child(4) > a')
}

getNewSurvey(){
    return cy.get('btn btn-success')
}
```

}
export default new BeHomePage();

As picture below shows all code in one (it) block passes as seen in picture however code in 2 it blocks fails as seen above.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT6TM.png)

Comment: I don't think the `before()` is executing more than once. In the Cypress log there is only one call to before logged. The app has a page redirect after logging in - `(new url)
https://automation-ozzie.boardeffect.com/`, this may be what you are seeing.

Comment: Okay how do i resolve the issue so that the redirect page loads?

Comment: What you think is wrong - does it not log in successfully?

Comment: when i set the basUrl it logs in successfully. However after the test case completes and it clicks getAutoBeWorkroom().click(); the page goes back to the initial sign in page causing the test that come after to fail. 

However if i use visit() with url inside after signin is clicked it appends some weird character onto the the end of the url.

Comment: You will need to post the code that causes the effect. i.e BeHomePage.

Comment: posted the BeHomePage Class

Comment: Also I just noticed something when i put the above code in 1 (it) block it executes but when i use 2 (it ) blocks it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra step you need is discussed in this section of the docs [Cookies - Preserve Once](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html#Preserve-Once).

Cypress auto-clears cookies between each `it()`, but if you add

```
it('user can login to boardeffect', () => {          
  LoginPage.getLoginUserName().type(Cypress.env('username'));
  LoginPage.getLoginUserPassword().type(Cypress.env('password'));
  LoginPage.getSigninButton().click();

  // preserve the cookie set above for the next test
  Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('_boardeffect_session'); 
})
```

it will keep that cookie value during subsequent `it()` sections.

Open the browser dev-tools, go to Application, Cookies, https://automation-ozzie.boardeffect.com and observe that without `preserveOnce()` the cookie value is cleared.

Comment: I okay i looked at that previously but did not understand. where do i put both lines of code is it in command.js file?

Comment: I put Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('_boardeffect_session') in command.js file and it seemed to resolve the issue between it statements continuing with the test however what do i do with the cy.contains('Log in to BoardEffect').click();